# How to create alias for type?

Tags: typescript

I have a lot of function with generic type `KEY extends keyof Setting` in order to restrict types. For example:

```js
setValue('name', 'Alex') // ok
setValue('name', false) // error
setValue('name', 30) // error
setValue('isVerified', true) // ok

type Setting = {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    isVerified: boolean,
}

type SettingObject<KEY extends keyof Setting> = { [P in KEY]: Setting[P] }

async function setValue<KEY extends keyof Setting>(key: KEY, value: Setting[KEY]): Promise<void> { ... }

async function setValueArray<KEY extends keyof Setting>(values: SettingObject<KEY>): Promise<void> { ... }

async function getValue<KEY extends keyof Setting>(key: KEY): Promise<Setting[KEY]> { ... }

async function getValueArray<KEY extends keyof Setting>(keys: KEY[]): Promise<SettingObject<KEY>> { ... }
```

Is there way to create short alias for `KEY extends keyof Setting`

```
// pseudocode
type SettingKey = KEY extends keyof Setting
```

Answer (score 1):

`KEY` is not a type, it's a *type argument*, you can't alias that. You can howewer alias `keyof Setting` like

```
type SKey = keyof Setting
// ...
type SettingObject<KEY extends SKey> = { [P in KEY]: Setting[P] }
```

Comment: Would be great if you add a link to TypeScript playground